# Why is the grid-row-gap different from the grid-column-gap?

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to use grid. I have set the grid-column-gap and grid-row-gap both to 10px but, as you can see, the two gaps appear of different sizes. Why is that?

[image]

I have tried to add margin:0 to the p as I have read this suggestion from previous threads. When I do so the grid-column-gap and grid-row-gap appear of the same size but the pink color of the main container disappears, why is that? Here the link to codepen https://codepen.io/Alicinetto/pen/NVqqmo

```css
.container {
  background: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

main>p {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <p>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,</p>
  <p>sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam
    quaerat voluptatem.</p>

</main>
```

Comment: for me they are exacly the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `<p>` element has native top and bottom margins applied by the browser's default stylesheet. If you set `margin: 0` on the `<p>` element then the issue will go away.

```css
main>p {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you want to retain some separation between the container and it's inner `<p>` elements, then set a `10px` padding on `.container`:

```css
.container {
  background: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

main>p {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <p>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,</p>
  <p>sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam
    quaerat voluptatem.</p>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

The paragraphs have margin on the bottom. If you add

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

the row gaps are the same.